# having issue in Server components in next js

Tags: authentication, next.js, cookies, nestjs

I've implemented cookies and JWT authentication in my NestJS backend. Now I'm working on the Next.js frontend, and I have a server component that sends a request to the backend (Nest) to get protected data. However, I'm receiving an "unauthorized" message from the backend in the server component.
Note: I'm using HTTPS-only cookies and ngrok for HTTPS in development. When i send reqeust from the client component directly to the backend (nest js) i am not getting the unauthorized response means i getting the desired result

How to solve this? means how i can configure next js

How i can forward the incomming reqeust details (such a secure cookies that is send by the browser ) from the server componets to backend end point (Nest js) becasue everything is working as expected in the client compoents

i want the server componets  in some way forwards all the request details to the backend in nest js